# iPhone FTP Connection

Tags: iphone, ftp

I am working on an iPhone app for a client that needs to be able to manipulate directories on an arbitrary FTP server.

Does anybody know of any FTP libraries, frameworks, sample code that can remove directories from an FTP server?

*NOTE*: I have thoroughly researched CFFTP and the SimpleFTP Sample code provided by Apple and it only supports half of the FTP protocol(I don't know why there is only half of the implementation).

Comment: there is an sample code for that, check taht out [FTP SAMPLE CODE](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/index.html)

Comment: As I stated in my original post, I have thoroughly researched CFFTP and the SimpleFTPSample code provided by Apple.  From my understanding CFFTP only supports Upload, Download, Directory Creation and Directory Listing.

Can you prove otherwise?

Comment: It is possible to remove a directory, but you must empty it first. You could use [this](https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon). Or you could have a look at the code to see how folder deletion is done.

Comment: I have checked out your code . +1 ,it is working fine in simulator. where as i have tried to build @ device ,it through error. any thing i need to specific for device??Error @ device ,.m file upload & dowmload implementation classes through streamInfo & didManagedToOpenStream are undeclared . but same code Working fine in simulator.please provide some solution for this issue

Comment: :Plz can u provide some solution for above problem

Comment: Please see the github answer.

Comment: aka be sure to have the latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If guess you could use [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) if you have little success with the apple sample code, [see here](http://www.intelliproject.net/articles/showArticle/index/use_curl_iphone_sdk).

Comment: Any help on the FTP libraries I asked about?

Comment: Not sure of any libraries, but I think you should be able to delete a directory/file by passing regular FTP commands via cURL, see http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/320/using-curl-to-access-ftp-server/.

Comment: @collin, do you have try to build libcurl from that link? can you give me a clue? because i try all of that steps, but when i build from Xcode, it gives me thousands error, can you help me? it's really make me crazy